# Unable to save image from the directory using FileProvider

Tags: android, image-processing, android-fileprovider

I'm taking an photo with my device's camera using FileProvider but the image was not being saved in the directory or in any other directory. How do I fix the problem so that I can save the captured image in a directory?

MainActivity.java

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

 File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Test-Folder");

        if (!storageDir.exists()) {
            storageDir.mkdirs();
        }

File image = new File(storageDir, "QR_" + timeStamp + ".png");
Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "com.test", image);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);

List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList =
                getPackageManager()
                        .queryIntentActivities(cameraIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
            String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            grantUriPermission(packageName, photoUri,
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

        }
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<external-path name="external_files" path="Test-Folder/"/>

</paths>
```

Comment: Perhaps the camera app on this particular device does not support `content` `Uri` values. Google's own camera app did not support the `content` scheme for videos until this summer, for example.

Comment: `storageDir.mkdirs();`. You should check the return value as mkdirs might fail and will return false then. In case it is false display a toast telling the user this and return. Do not continue with the rest of the code. I bet that the directory is not created to begin with.

Comment: @greenapps hey bud, mkdirs return false because I didn't put a write external storage permission in the manifest file. Thanks to you!

Comment: @CommonsWare I was now able to create and save image in the directory. i'm just wondering if there is a way to check if a device supports content uri?

Comment: The *device* is not the problem. The *camera app* is the problem. And, no, there is no way to detect if any given camera app supports a `content` scheme for `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. My best recommendation is for you to keep your `targetSdkVersion` below 24 for as long as you can, so you can continue using `file` schemes, while the world's camera apps (hopefully) upgrade to start supporting `content`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
storageDir.mkdirs();
```

The code above returns ***false***, this is because I didn't put a permission to write in the external storage. I added the following code in my android manifest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<!-- other code here-->   

</manifest>
```

Thanks to ***greenapp*** for pointing out the storageDir.mkdirs.

Comment: `I bet that the directory is not created to begin with.`. So where is my reward? ;-).